# How to combine remote and local players?

Tags: remote

One of our players now lives in other country. He was devastated for not being able to play, but we solved that with Skype.

Well, kinda. There are some difficulties when all players are sitting on the table and one is via a remote conversation. He loses some details and players' conversations. That sucks a little, as he is in disadvantage with the rest of players.

But today things will be worse. Today we'll combat. I find very difficult keeping him up with battle information, combatants positions, health levels and such. It will be chaotic and I fear my friend can have a frustrating experience.

Using an online tool like Maptool seems not the best option, as the other players sitting at the table will have a hard time looking at the laptop to know player's position.

So, I'm interested in wise advice, successful experiences and inspired ideas about how to avoid these communications problems, how to get this player involved and specially how to manage combats.

It's a generic question, but if someone wants to know what kind of game we are playing it's Dark Ages: Vampire, and changing game is not an option, since this chronicle is what players are interested to.